# using the data returned from server in angular ngrepeat

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What I've been trying to do is get a data from the server using $http service of angular.js and then use the returned data in my template using ng-repeat directive. But the problem is that the data fetched are not being displayed at all, and the ng-repeat directive is generating like a number rows, except the one that it should. I am using PHP to render data. This is the javascript part:

```
    function display($scope, $http){
      $scope.s= "?s=Spice";
      $http({method: "GET", url: "getlistangular.php"+$scope.s}).
       success(function(data){
        alert("success");
        $scope.list= data;
       }).
       error(function(){
        alert("failed");
           });
     }
```

This is the script in php (spname, spprice, imgsrc are column names in mysql 'spice' table):

```
    $t = $_GET['s'];
    $query= mysql_query("select * from $t");

    echo "[";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
    echo "{img:'".$row[imgsrc]."', name:'".$row[spname]."', price:'".$row[spprice]."'},\n";
    }
    echo "];";
```

& this is the template part:

```
    <table ng-controller="display">

                <tr>
                    <th> </th> <th> Name </th> <th> Price (Rs.) </th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="con in list">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" value={{con.name}}><img src="{{con.img}}"/></td>
                    <td>{{con.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{con.price}}</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Am new to this angular.js thing, so if you find it a silly question, i apologize for it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please give sample data which is coming from server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript Should be this :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('displayCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.s= "?s=Spice";
  $http({method: "GET", url: "getlistangular.php"+$scope.s, isArray: true}) //change here
    .success(function(response){
       alert("success");
       $scope.list= response; //change here
    })
    .error(function(){
       alert("failed");
    });
 });
```

HTML Part :

```
<table ng-controller="display">
```

Replace to :

```
<table  ng-controller="displayCtrl">
```

And

```
 <html>
```

Replace To

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
```

See [DEMO HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/asByvRR4lSVsamS3x2BQ?p=preview)

Comment: this ain't working nitish..:( surprisingly, the data when fetched from the server is in the form as you have mentioned in data.json, but it is unable to use those to display in the template via ngrepeat.

Comment: The error is basically, that in the output, no name or price is being displayed, but there are a number of irrelevant checkboxes, and blank images without img src. Can you just try fetching the data from a mysql table, instead of keeping the data predefined? because i think you may understand the scenario better that way.

Comment: can you give data whic you getting from ajax call

Comment: Instead of assigning the returned data from the server to the $scope.list variable, if I am alerting it I am getting data as: [{img:'images/pic1.jpg', name:'pic1', price: '20'}, {img:'images/pic3.jpg', name:'pic3', price: '30'}, {img:'images/pic2.jpg', name:'pic2', price: '40'},];

Comment: i changed something in controller and now try

Comment: where are the changes please?

Comment: $http({method: "GET", url: "getlistangular.php"+$scope.s, isArray: true}) 

$scope.list= response;

Comment: :( not working..the same result.. a number of rows, without any data thats needed.

Comment: i think you are making mistake in html

Comment: can you give more html where you are rendering ng-repeat

Comment: i already gave you the code..and if i make those data static ( like defining $scope.list without calling the php file), it works awesome.

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="con in list">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="regular-checkbox" value={{con.name}}><img src="{{con.img}}"/></td>
                    <td>{{con.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{con.price}}</td>
                </tr>

Comment: Are you getting lot of rows in html

Comment: yep the same output, a number of checkboxes..but if instead of using the code in php that I mentioned above, if I store the data in an array and return the response as an json array, i am getting 3 rows, but they all are blank.. :(

Comment: please give data in an array and return the response as an json array.
as Sample

Comment: $t = $_GET['s'];
$query= mysql_query("select * from $t");

$arr = array();
$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$i++;
$arr[$i]= "{'img':'".$row[imgsrc]."', 'name':'".$row[spname]."', 'price':'".$row[spprice]."'},\n";
}
echo json_encode($arr);

Comment: please use like this
It is a correct Way

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{ 
  $arr[] =  array(
    'img' => $row['imgsrc'],
    'name' => $row['spname'],
    'price' => $row['spprice']
    );
}

echo json_encode(array('data' => $arr)):

Comment: i did it, but still the same output..didnt make any difference.

Comment: are you added isArray: true in $http ?

Comment: yep..and the wierd part is that now its creating the proper number of rows, but unfortunately not populating any data..

Comment: add <td>{{con}}</td> in tr and see what are u getting here

Comment: same output..3 rows, with this prepended : {"img":null,"name":null,"price":null}

Comment: am new to this forum as well, if you can give me your email id i'll mail you the html file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was basically in the php part..the solution is to return a json array in key:value format instead of creating it using echo:

```
    echo "[";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo "{img:'".$row[imgsrc]."', name:'".$row[spname]."', price:'".$row[spprice]."'},\n";
}
echo "];";
```

should be replaced by:

```
    $arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
$arr[] = array( 'img' => $row['imgsrc'], 'name' => $row['spname'], 'price' => $row['spprice'] );
}

echo json_encode(array('data' => $arr));
```